# FOREIGN KEY constraint May cause cycles or multiple paths

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have read tons of articles seemingly similar to my issue, but just haven't been able to arrive at my ideal solution.

My specific error says:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Scores_Tees_TeeId' on table 'Scores' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

So, the table in question here, looks like this:

```
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ScoreId { get; set; }
        public int Strokes { get; set; }
        public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
        public Guid CourseId { get; set; }
        public Guid TeeId { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TeeId")]
        public virtual Tee Tee { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, this table references Tees table, shown here:

```
    public class Tee
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid TeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Par { get; set; }
        public int Yards { get; set; }
        public float Rating { get; set; }
        public int Slope { get; set; }
        public Guid CourseId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    }
```

I read about making the TeeId nullable in the Scores table. I did that and was able to build run my migration successfully... however I do need this field to be required. If that id is empty/null then I don't have enough information about that particular Score record.

Answer (score 0):

Both `Tee` and `Score` have a required reference to `Course`.  When you delete a referenced `Course`, EF will want to delete the associated `Tee` and `Score`.  When `Tee` is deleted, EF will again want to delete the associated `Score`.  This is the "multiple cascade path" problem.

This error brings to light a problem with the design; the two references to `Course` can be different values which makes no sense in the context used (the score is for one course while referencing a "tee" from another course?).  You should refactor your design.

Tees in golf are usually a small subset of value by either color (blue, white, gold, red) or name (ladies', back/champions', seniors, etc).  One way to resolve your design issue is to normalize these name and/or color values in a `Tee` table, then have a `CourseTee` table that defines the properties of the `Course`'s tees.  This would be done by using a compound key either as primary key or candidate key (called alternate key in EF) composed of FK's to `Course` and `Tee`.  This entity is where you would then define the properties of the course's tees:

```
public class CourseTee
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; ]
    [Key]
    public Guid TeeId { get; set; }
    public Tee Tee { get; set; }

    public int Par { get; set; }
    // additional course-tee specific properties
    ...
}

public class Score  // as a golfer, change this to `Round`
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ScoreId { get; set; }  // RoundId :D
    public Person Player { get; set; }
    public CourseTee CourseTee { get; set; }
    public int Strokes { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Tee
{
    public Guid TeeId { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now `Course` is only defined once in a `Score`'s object graph.  To get the `Course` for a given `Score` is simply an extra hop: `score.CourseTee.Course`

Comment: It's great to get some feedback from a fellow golfer. The CourseTee table created above, what is that type of table called? It doesn't seem to quite be a 'join' table because it's not defining a many-to-many relationship. Unless by 'normalizing' you're saying that every course will be considered to have a 'blue', 'white', 'gold', 'red' tee. In which case the 'blue' tee would have a 'many' relationship back to Courses.

Comment: Yes, define the tees once and associate them with as many courses as required. The table also holds the course specific properties for the tee type (slope, par, etc).